# Android Round Button and Spinner inside Activity Group

Tags: android

I have a Spinner and 2 buttons in an Activity Group. I want to apply rounded corner to the buttons. I have created shape xml resource file for round button in Android. I have assigned this resource file as background to the button while creating the button in Layout. But the change is not reflected after executing the application.

I have set the ContentView for that screen as :

```
setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.textmessage,null));
```

This has to be done to make spinner work in an Activity Group.
How can I make the Button as round corner in an Activity Group having Spinner?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: jst set the image having rounded corners to the button as background.no need to create xml file

Comment: and no need to inflate layout to setcontent view,pass only layout in it

Comment: Spinner does not work if we pass layout directly to the setcontentview. We need to inflate to make spinner to work properly inside an Activity Group.

Comment: i said no need to inflate layout/xml for button background.set image as background to button having rounded corners

Comment: I want to create button through coding as I don't have image for that button.

Answer (score 0):

Call setBackgroundResource method on the button and pass in the xml file for the button shape.

Also, as a double check, make sure your button appears rounded using a regular Activity and standard layout file.

FYI ActivityGroup is now deprecated.

Comment: I tried to set the Button Background using setBackgroundResource method. But the change is not reflected in Activity Group having Spinner in it. For regular activities in Activity Group, it works fine.

Comment: Forget the Activity Group for a second. Can you show your Activity, alone, not part of a group, with the Spinner and the Button with rounded corners? I think you need to post some of the code you are using for Activity Group and the Activity with the button. Maybe you are referencing the wrong button or something. Some of the things you are posting don't quite make sense without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file in the res/drawable folder.
xml file code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <solid android:color="#dadada"/> 
    <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="13dip"
     android:topRightRadius="13dip"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="13dip"
     android:bottomRightRadius="13dip"/>
</shape>
```

---

after that open the button xml file and set attribute of button as
android:background = "@drawable/xml file name"

hope it helps you.

Comment: I have created shape resource file similar to above. For normal Activity screens it works fine. But in Activity Group which has spinner,the change is not reflected.

Comment: set button attribute programatically like - Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xml file name);

Comment: I have tried to set Button background programatically as well. Still it does not work in Activity group which has spinner.